# Get top 10 messages from MSMQ

Tags: c#, msmq, message-queue

I have built a service to take messages from one queue and send them to 4 others.
All works well, but I have to amend it now to only take the top 10 messages at a time.
At the moment Im using the .GetAllMessages() method on the queue Im taking from, can anyone advise how I can amend this to take only 10?

thanks

Comment: Do you want to dequeue them as well? Then, in the next iteration, there will be 10 other messages.

Comment: Yes, at the moment I just get all, then once moved to the other queues I purge the original queue, but now I have to remove 10 at a time to the other queues.

Comment: What about dequeuing 10 times?

Comment: would that be using .Receive() rather than .GetAllMessages()?

Comment: It is such an arbitrary number, merely an evolutionary accident.  Why not 1?  Make it work for 1 and then just do it 10 times.  At least you'll stand a chance to avoid deadlocking yourself when the queue has only 9 messages.  Using GetMessageEnumerator2() is never wrong.